# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero in JAVA NETBEANS

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been working on a project. I have a form where user details would be entered alongside their profile photo being uploaded.

But im stuck with this error while trying to retrieve user profile photo when I search their records from the database using `txt_searchKeyReleased` method.

I get the error 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero`

which occurs at line where im pulling the image from the DB as below

`byte[] image=rs.getBytes("Image");
                ImageIcon imageicon=new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(image).getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl_image.getWidth(),lbl_image.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                lbl_image.setIcon(imageicon);`

I am storing the image directly to the database as a `LONGBLOB`. I would appreciate a correction so as to be able to retrieve the users profile photo.
And also to be able to store users profile photo into a folder within my project and store its path along with their details in the database.

Comment: The error message is very clear right? You need to pass non-zero values for width and height to create the `ImageIcon`

Comment: @javaguy  some lines of code would be  highly appreciated